# Lock the events for attendees in google calendar is not working

Tags: google-app-engine, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am creating an event to my calendar and added an attendees to that event. As specified in the doc [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/whats-new#google_events_in_calendar_api_v3) We can prevent the event from editing by the attendees. But it's now working as expected. Can anyone help me.

Here's how I am trying....

```
        Event event = new Event().setSummary("sampleEvent").setDescription("eventsummary");

        DateTimeHelper obDateTimeHelper = new DateTimeHelper();
        DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime(obDateTimeHelper.funGetNowInMillisecondsInThisTimeZone("UTC"));
        EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime().setDateTime(startDateTime).setTimeZone("UTC");
        event.setStart(start);

        DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime(obDateTimeHelper.funGetNowInMillisecondsInThisTimeZone("UTC"));
        EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime().setDateTime(endDateTime).setTimeZone("UTC");
        event.setEnd(end);

        event.setLocked(true);
        event.setVisibility("private");
        event.setGuestsCanInviteOthers(false);
        event.setGuestsCanModify(false);
        event.setGuestsCanSeeOtherGuests(false);
        EventAttendee[] attendee = new EventAttendee[]{ new EventAttendee().setEmail("attendee@gmail.com") };
        event.setAttendees(Arrays.asList(attendee));

        Calendar calendarService = getCalendarService(accessToken);

        event = calendarService.events().insert(calendarId, event).setOauthToken(accessToken).execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

"This field is read-only." is at the end of the documentation to which you pointed. That means you cannot set this property yourself.

Comment: oh then is there any other way that I can prevent the attendee from editing the event?

Comment: But with this "event.setLocked(true);" I'm able to set the value. and log also says so that this property is set with value "true".

Comment: There are very many read-only properties which client libraries allow you to set but don't actually get persisted on the server side. CalendarList entries for example contain timezone and calendar title and none of those you can actually set through calendar list, despite that you will see setters. I propose you re-read the event and see whether the locked property is returned.